# UIWebView Upload Multiple selected Image from Photo Library Not Working

Tags: swift, uiwebview, image-uploading

How can we get webview to allow for multiple files selected through UIWebView "choose file" when uploading images from the iOS device?

Using Swift, we have a UIWebView with a file upload option inside the web view.  When the user clicks CHOOSE FILE in the webview, iOS allows multiple selection of images, however the webview CHOOSE FILE only allows ONE IMAGE selected.

Is there a way to LIMIT the PHOTO LIBRARY to choose only ONE IMAGE and not MULTIPLE IMAGES?

Thank you!